# Load image path dynamically when rendering component in reactjs. Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load an image source path dynamically from the props value when rendering my component.

This is my code:

```
render(){
    let image;
    image = require('../../assets/img/grid-list/test.jpg'); // this works!
    this.props.gridListData.values.map(tile => tile.imagem = require(tile.img) ); // this breaks with Error: Cannot find module '../../assets/img/grid-list/test.jpg'
  }
```

The value of tile.img is '../../assets/img/grid-list/test.jpg'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
this.props.gridListData.values.map(tile => tile.imagem = require(`${tile.img}`) );
```

`require` waits for a path as a string, does not work dynamically with variables. This is some kind of a workaround.

Comment: `tile.img` is a string which keeps the path, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. Its value is '../../assets/img/grid-list/test.jpg'

Comment: @sopaDaBahia, I'm sure that `require` should work like that here but I haven't noticed before but you are using `map` wrong. There is an assignment and `map` does not work like that. Can we see your whole component or just the related parts at least? Why am I sure `require` should work? You can see [an example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y0o5ymzpj).